# Angular $resource setup : Communicating between factory services

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4, angularjs-directive, angular-resource, angular-services

I am trying to implement pagination for my `Laravel 4 + angular.js 1.0.7` application by reading [this article](http://kirkbushell.me/pagination-with-laravel-4-and-angular-js/).

My code looks,

```
var app = angular.module('cmsPlus', ['ngResource']);

app.service( 'Post', [ '$resource', function( $resource ) {
   return $resource( 'posts/:id', { id: '@id'} );
}]);

function PostCtrl($scope, $http, Post) {
   $scope.init = function () {
     console.log(Post); // returns empty object
     $scope.posts = Post.query(); // Post.query is not a function
     // $scope.posts = Post.get(); // Post.get is not a function
   }
}
```

Why I am getting empty object with `console.log(Post);`? And why it shows `Post.query is not a function` error? How can I solve it?

### Edit: Communicating between two factory services

Now I have two factory services,

```
app.factory('Data', function(){
        return {
            root_path: "<?php echo Request::root(); ?>/"
        };
});

app.factory( 'Post', [ '$resource', function( $resource ) {
   return $resource( 'posts/:id', { id: '@id'} );
}]);
```

How can I access `Data.root_path` in `Post` factory service?

Comment: Change your service to see if it's getting called.  Use `var r = $resource(...);` and `console.dir(r);` then `return r;`.  Is it getting called and what does the value look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use factory instead of service, i.e.:

```
app.factory( 'Post', [ '$resource', 'Data', function( $resource, Data ) {
   return $resource( Data.root_path + 'posts/:id', { id: '@id'} );
}]);
```

This link shows the difference:

http://blog.manishchhabra.com/2013/09/angularjs-service-vs-factory-with-example/

Comment: Thanks. It's working, how can I communicate between two factory services? see updated question.